# Return "not found" after installing magento CE 2.1.6 in subdirectory

Tags: magento2

I installed CE 2.1.6 in subdirectory via command line as linode(linux host) guided: 
/var/www/html/mydomain.com/public_html

Installing is finished, then i went to the admin url like mydomain.com/admin_f3fds3, it returns me "not found". admin_f3fds3 is the uri it gave after installing.

And when i went to frontend, it redirected me to the following url:
http://tgqpauxpaf.info/index.php/?SID=v31er0705khgm3evn2vf3nraq5

What should i do next, has anyone installed magento like this?

LAMP: ubuntu0.16.04.1 
Appach 2.4 
Mysql 5.7.18 
PHP 7.0.15 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try add index.php to you admin url:
mydomain.com/index.php/yourAdminPath ?

You can check admin path in console:

```
php bin/magento info:adminuri
```

As regards second issue, please try regenerate static content, run below command:

```
php bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy
```